# casting JPA Native query result in Java

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

When I run a native JPA query like this: `"select name from customer where id = 100"` and `name` is varchar2 in db, the native query returns an Object. Can I cast it to String directly in java or do I have to manipulate it like a ResultSet?

Comment: If you want type safety, you have to look for CriteriaBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getResultList will return a List, you can cast the value in the list to a String.

getSingleResult will return Object, you can cast it to a String.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Native query with JPA/Hibernate, the use of @SqlResultSetMapping annotation
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/query_native.html